# Cannot access jenkins in virtual machine

Tags: jenkins, virtualbox

I have virtualbox with Ubuntu 14.10 server, Jenkins and Apache installed. When I access the IP of this virtualbox the homepage of apache is load correctly. But when I try to acces jenkins via x.x.x.x:8080 (ip of my virtualbox) it won't load. I only get a connection time out error

I tried to configure a different port (8081 and 6060) but that doesn't work. I also add a port forwarding to VirtualBox but that doesn't work ether...
[image]

Anyone suggestions how I can acces jenkins that is running inside a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you need the box to be accessible by machines other than your host, you need a bridged or host-only network interface https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

I've just done a full install of Nginx, Java, and Jenkins:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

on a fresh Ubuntu VirtualBox instance where the first interface is Host-only and the second is NAT:

[image]

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Host-only interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address         192.168.56.20
        netmask         255.255.255.0
        network         192.168.56.0
        broadcast       192.168.56.255

# NAT interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

I can reach Jenkins from my host on 192.168.56.20:8080 with no port forwarding necessary. You must have something unrelated to Jenkins going on, possibly firewall related. Try setting Jenkins back to 8080, removing your port forwarding, and check for firewall rules that could be getting in the way.

Comment: Adapter 2 is a host-only-adapter, but I cannot setup port forwarding there

Comment: When you added the host-only adapter in VirtualBox did you also add the interface in Ubuntu?